# Diff. Eq. classes say that there are non-differentiable solutions to Diff. Eqs. What are they considering to be a *valid* solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

To give a really simplistic example, the differential equations class would consider $y' = u(x) - u(-x)$ to have a solution of $y = |x|$.*

The natural issue that arises is that the absolute value function does not have a derivative at $0$ and so that cannot be a valid solution. Yet, it is proposed that it is a solution. The question then arises then:

> In what sense is that being considered as a solution to a differential equation?

---

*$u(x)$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: My wild guess: maybe in the sense that it's continuous everywhere, and satisfies the differential equation everywhere except where the input function is discontinuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be seen as a [weak solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution) to the equation. The idea is that you extend the concept of differentiability of a function so the equation has a new meaning.

To do this, you define the concept of a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) which you can think of as a generalisation of a function. Some, but not all, distributions correspond (in a precise sense) to ordinary functions.

Then you can define the derivative of a distribution in such a way that all distributions become differentiable and the derivatives of the distributions which correspond to ordinary functions correspond to their ordinary derivatives.

Now you can reinterpret at a differential equation as being a problem about differentiation of distributions. Since there are strictly more distributions than functions, there is the possibility of additional solutions (called weak solutions) which don't correspond to ordinary differentiable functions. However, original solutions to the equation remain solutions.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: for 1-dimensional problems (i.e. ODEs, not PDEs), weak solutions are always continuous; but there are many other ways to define  "generalized solutions", so it's hard to be sure exactly what is meant.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: Right, the weak solution $f$ will be continuous, but its weak derivative $f'$ (which is used in the definition of weak solutions) can be quite ugly.